# Видимость в фоновом потоке значения, измененного в главном потоке

Tags: java, concurrency

В этом коде есть проблема: фоновый поток не остановится никогда. Почему это происходит? В книге объяснение такое: без синхронизации нет гарантированного времени, когда фоновый поток увидит измененное в основном потоке значение `stopRequested`.

```
import java.util.concurrent.TimeUnit;

public class Main {

    private static boolean stopRequested;

    public static void main(String[] args) throws InterruptedException {
        System.out.println("Started");
        Thread backgroundThread = new Thread(() -> {
            int i = 0;
            while (!stopRequested)
                i++;
        });
        backgroundThread.start();
        TimeUnit.SECONDS.sleep(1);
        stopRequested = true;
        System.out.println("Finished");
    }
}
```

А почему этого гарантированного времени нет?

Здесь дело только в оптимизации компилятора, или есть другие нюансы? Автор предлагает заменить синхронизацию на `volatile`. По си я помню, что `volatile` заставляет компилятор при обращении к переменной постоянно читать ее из памяти, а не оптимизировать операции чтения.

Comment: А вы проверяли? Действительно поток не завершается?

Comment: Проверял. Не завершается.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Читая не volatile переменную, ее значение может быть, и скорее всего будет,прочитано из кеша процессора. То есть, присвоив ей значение, фоновый поток продолжает упорно читать свое старое значение переменной в кэше, так как он быстрее.

Вариантов два: сделать переменную volatile, тогда значение всегда будет записываться и читаться из оперативной памяти либо сделать фоновый поток демоном, тогда он умрет, когда остальные обычные потоки завершаться

upd

Могу ошибаться, но предположительно, поведение может отличаться для разный процессов в зависимости от объема кеша, их количества, алгоритмов их работы. Скажем, если поток будет использовать большее количество переменных, чем это позволяет кеш процессора, то они будут читаться из оперативной памяти напрямую. Это упирается уже в аппаратную часть и у каждого производителя алгоритм работы может отличаться

Answer (score 0):

Для таких целей используют AtomicBoolean, а не volatile.